# else/if in service dependency or alternative

Tags: angularjs

[image] I have a few modules (`Main`, `Secondary`), and they have dependency - `Stuff`, from `Stuff` both services using `Service`. So `Service` from `Stuff` is working in `Main` service couse dependecy `Factory` is exist only in Main service. But in `Secondary` isn't work, couse `Factory` is dependency of `Main` service.

```
    angular.module('Main', ['Stuff']);
    angular.module('Secondary', ['Stuff']);

    angular.module('Stuff', []);
    angular.module('Stuff').service('Service', ['Factory', function(Factory){}])
    angular.module('Main').factory('Factory', function(){})
```

Without another adding to dependency can I make some inspection like :
`Factory` ? `Factory` : null, to `Secondary` service, couse I don't need `Factory` in this service, this service has his own `Factory` :) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once modules are loaded, it is no longer known which module the service belongs to. There's only one `Factory`, which is overridden by the last module that defined it (`Main`).

To avoid colliding, namespaces can be used:

```
angular.module('stuff').service('service', ['stuff.factory', function(factory){...}])
angular.module('main').factory('main.factory', function(){...});
```

If the service may not exist in the application at all (optional dependency), the pattern is

```
angular.module('stuff').service('service', ['$injector', function($injector){
  var factory = $injector.has('factory') ? $injector.get('factory') : null;
  ...
}])
```

Comment: but `main` don't know about `secondary` so I guess will be error about - error unknown injection stuff.factory, couse `secondary` is using `service`

Comment: It isn't possible for me to figure out their relationship from the question. Please, provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In bootstrapped application every loaded module 'knows' about another, that's what the answer says. Just to make it clear, what does `this service has his own Factory` exactly mean?

Comment: Yes, the part with `main2` wasn't revealed in the question, it is relevant. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thx! I think it helps, few sec ago I find this way in documentation, thx for your help!!